# How to replace string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, replace, xml2js

I am trying to replace `'<p>hi</p>'` with 'hi'

My JavaScript:

```
var obj = {item:{title: params.title,description: params.text, link: req.headers['origin']+"/blog/blog-description/"+params.blog_id, guid:req.headers['origin']+"/blog/blog-description/"+params.blog_id}};

var xml2js = require('xml2js');     
var builder = new xml2js.Builder();
var xml = builder.buildObject(obj);
var modXml = xml.replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>', '');
var modXml = xml.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');         
var new_text = modXml;

fs.readFile('public/feed.xml', function read(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var file_content = data.toString();
    var c = file_content.indexOf('</description>');
    var position = c + 14;
    file_content = file_content.substring(position);
    var file = fs.openSync('public/feed.xml','r+');
    var bufferedText = new Buffer(new_text+file_content);
    fs.writeSync(file, bufferedText, 0, bufferedText.length, position);
    fs.close(file);
});
```

i didnt know where it went wrong can someone suggest help.

Comment: So what issue are you running across? I don't see a question here.

Comment: Instead of replacing the header, just call `new xml2js.Builder({headless: true});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xml2js replaces your `<p>` tag with `&lt;p&gt;` (and the `</p>` with `&lt;/p&gt;`), so you need to replace the replaced string. Also, call `Builder()` with the `headless: true` option - then you don't need to replace the header. The following works:

```
var obj = {item:{title: '<p>foobarbaz</p>',description: "<p>foo</p>", link: "<p>bar</p>", guid:"<p>baz</p>"}};

var xml2js = require('xml2js');
var builder = new xml2js.Builder({ headless: true });
var xml = builder.buildObject(obj);
var modXml = xml.replace(/&lt;p&gt;|&lt;\/p&gt;/gm, '');
console.log(modXml);
```

Output:

```
<item>
  <title>fobaba</title>
  <description>foo</description>
  <link>bar</link>
  <guid>baz</guid>
</item>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ,,,,,,,

Comment: Is it possible to append only first 100 words of my description.

Comment: Sure, use substring: str.substring(0, 99)

Comment: Thanks,how to replce only </br> tag in xml

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
xml.split('<p>hi</p>').join('hi');
```

Answer (score 1):

Since replace is returning a string object, you can simply chain the calls:

Have you tried:

```js
var modXml = xml.replace('<p>', '').replace("</p>",'');
```

I think you could also condense it into one regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

you could either use a regex to strip tags, or use a library such as [striptags](https://github.com/ericnorris/striptags)

optional regex:

```js
var text = '<p>aaa</p>';
console.log(text.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, ''));
```

striptags library could be used to strip all tags, or only specific tags:

```
var text = '<p>aaa</p>';
striptags(html);
striptags(html, ['p']);
```

Comment: Thank you,MoLow but it says replace is not deined

Comment: that means your variable is not a string. in your case, try `xml.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '')`

Comment: still it is not removing i will edit the code pls have  a look

Comment: I don't see any problem. maybe the html tags you are trying to replace are in `file_content`, and not in `new_text`?

Comment: Molow,i replaced the step here,but not wrking    var file_content = data.toString();
                        var file_content = file_content.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
                        var c = file_content.indexOf('</description>');